# Omit the time value

Tags: oracle

In an Oracle database, I need to omit the time value output from this query:

```
select * 
from tbraccd inner join TBBDETC on TBRACCD_DETAIL_CODE=TBBDETC_DETAIL_CODE
where tbraccd.TBRACCD_EFFECTIVE_DATE >  to_date ('2021/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
  AND tbraccd.TBRACCD_EFFECTIVE_DATE <= to_date ('2022/07/1' , 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Answer (score 0):

As `DATE` datatype columns - in Oracle - contain time component, **one option** is to truncate that column so that you'd "remove" (actually, set to midnight) time component:

```
SELECT
    a.*,
    b.*,
    trunc(a.tbraccd_effective_date) tbraccd_effective_date
FROM
         tbraccd a
    INNER JOIN tbbdetc b ON a.tbraccd_detail_code = b.tbbdetc_detail_code
WHERE
        a.tbraccd_effective_date > TO_DATE('2021/12/31', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
    AND a.tbraccd_effective_date <= TO_DATE('2022/07/1', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

---

**Another** option is to apply `to_char` function with desired format model and omit time part:

```
SELECT
    to_char(a.tbraccd_effective_date, 'yyyy/mm/dd) tbraccd_effective_date
```

---

**Yet another** option is to modify session's date format; doing so, you don't have to modify query you wrote:

```
alter session set nls_date_format = 'yyyy/mm/dd';

select *
from ...
```

---

Finally, if you're running that query in some reporting tool, see if columns' **properties** offer formatting. If so, set it to desired value, e.g. `yyyy/mm/dd`.